# query mongodb 3.6 collection for document created in the last 24 hours

Tags: php, mongodb

**query mongodb 3.6 collection for document created in the last 24 hours in php.**

**collection**:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a85b8d7a7c1cb1f380000a6"),
    "userid" : "matt",
    "post" : "the value of human life",
    "message" : [ ],
    "imgsrc" : "/images/pic.jpg",
    "state" : "lagos",
    "repost" : [ ],
    "updated" : "2018-02-15 17:44:07",
    "created" : "2018-02-15 17:44:07"
}
```

Comment: db.collectionName.find({"created":{"$gte":new Date()}}).pretty()

Comment: The date "created" is stored as a string and new Date()  returns an isoDate(). Am i supposed to store the date as isoDate originally, and how. Thank you

Comment: Better to store in ISO format that will be easy to query.

Answer (score 0):

using mongodb aggregates,

```
use MongoDB;
$this->connection = new MongoDB\Client("mongodb://localhost:27017");
private $dbname = 'database';
private $db;
private $collection;
$this->db = $this->connection->{$this->dbname};
$this->collection = $this->db->collection;


$date = Date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime("-24 hours"));
$pipeline = array(
['$match' =>[
    ['created' =>['$gt'=> $this->timedate->setDate($date)]]
]                
]);
$query = $this->collection->aggregate($pipeline);
return $query->toArray();
```